# Add native footer view to webview

Tags: android, scroll, webview, footer, measure

I have a `WebView` and a native custom view I want to add underneath the `WebView`.  I've tried wrapping the `WebView` inside a `ScrollView`, and while that does exactly what i want, the scrolling performance is really laggy and if a user flings the scroll tapping the screen does not stop the fling like it should.

The other approach I was thinking was to inflate the `WebView` into a wrapper `FrameLayout` with my footer view on top of the `WebView`, then somehow extend the `WebView` height to accomodate the footer size, push the footer view to the end of the `WebView`s height and then monitor the scroll of the `WebView` to move the footer with it.

I've setup the base class, my problem is extending the scrollable content in the `WebView`, and then pushing the footer to the bottom of the `WebView`s content; the main issue being that `WebView` isn't your typical android view and the page content load asynchronously (and thus the content size changes).

How can I extend the scrollable content of a `WebView`? And how can I set the native footer below the `WebView` content?

EDIT:

I don't actually use xml, the view is constructed in code like so:

```
public class WebViewWithFooter extends FrameLayout {

private ObservableWebView mWebView;//webview with scroll methods overridden for access
private FrameLayout mFooterContainer;

public WebViewWithFooter(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}


public WebViewWithFooter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}


public WebViewWithFooter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public WebViewWithFooter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}


private void init() {

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams footerParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams webviewParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    mWebView = new ObservableWebView(getContext());

    mFooterContainer = new FrameLayout(getContext());

    addView(mWebView, webviewParams);
    addView(mFooterContainer, footerParams);
}
}
```

Comment: could you show your xml layout?

Comment: edited the code above with my class (there isn't xml as it's constructed in code)

Comment: maybe you can consider create your custom view group whose job is to layout the web view and footer. I feel like if you want exact control of the way you described, the best bet is do layout by yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap a simple `Webview`, with a footer (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc) inside an `ObservableScrollView`, rather than an `ObservableWebView`. I cannot go into details as you haven't added any layout files.

**EDIT**:

**Activity.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout   
   android:layout_width="match parent"  
   android:layout_height="match parent"  
   android:orientation="vertical">  
   <com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
           android:id="@+id/viewObj" 
           android:layout_width="match parent"  
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Webview and footer programatically added here -->
    </com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity.java**:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams footerParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams webviewParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
mFooterContainer = new FrameLayout(getContext());

mObservableScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewbyId(R.id.viewObj);
mObservableScrollView.addView(mWebView, webviewParams);
mObservableScrollView.addView(mFooterContainer, footerParams);
```

Comment: If you read the question properly you would have seen I have already tried and tested wrapping the webview and footer in a scrollview, and while it works, the scroll performance is very laggy, hence my request for a different approach

Comment: Yes i saw that. From the partial code, I gathered that you are using an 
ObservableWebView and attaching callbacks. Instead, attach your callbacks to an ObservableScrollView.

Comment: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this using layout xml code as follows:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/readme_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/changelog_text" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/readme_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <cu.tellistico.ImageButtonText
            android:id="@+id/btn_gift"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:contentDescription="@string/btn_donate_info"
            custom:buttonBackground="@drawable/states_orange"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_gift"
            android:text="Donar"
            android:textColor="@color/text_orange" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Below the blue text there is a scrollable Webview, and a button footer. Is this valid for you?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you are trying to show/hide the footer when the `WebView` is scrolled, right? If so, I don't think you need a third party library to achieve this. You can extend the `WebView` and override the method `onScrollChanged()`. It is called when the horizontal or vertical scroll are changing. If the vertical scroll has changed and it is positive, show the footer, otherwise - hide it.

Another idea: have you tried the new design library shipped by Google? There is a convenient way to achieve such behavior for `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but basically you want to have your footer view at the bottom of the page and your webview take up all of the space that's left?

Why don't you just put your footer view inside a RelativeLayout with the alignParentBottom set to true, then have your WebView be above your custom view, with the height set to matchParent?